# Pairwise test and random effect for Beta regression

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, beta-regression

I have percentage areas values from 4 treatments (25 replicates per treatment). I would like to compare these percentages.

I am supposed to use a beta regression, because my response variable is a proportion (not resulting from a count). For other variables I use GLMM and then use the glht() function to get the significance of pairwise comparisons. This does not seem to work with my betareg model. **Is there any way to do that ?**

Also I would like to include random effects because of nested sampling protocol. From this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167340/beta-regression-with-random-effect-of-source-plot-in-two-seasons) this does not seem very appropriate/easy to do this with beta regression.

Do you have any suggestion ?

---

EDIT

---

Thanks to @rvl's comment I could calculate pairwise comparisons and extract group letters.

```
   library(lsmeans)
   library(betareg)       
   betalive = betareg(Live ~ Crop)
   live.rg <- ref.grid(betalive)        
   live.lsm = lsmeans(live.rg, "Crop")
   cld(live.lsm, alpha =  0.05)$.group
   > [1] " 1 " " 1 " " 1 " "  2"
```

However I could not solve my problem of random effects yet.

Comment: The lsmeans package supports betareg models. Look at ?models after loading the package for more info.

Comment: Thanks @rvl, I could compute pairwise comparisons with lsmeans